# Comparing current date to mysql date to update mysql event status and all dates are coming out the same although they are not

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to update the status of each of my events in my "Events" table by updating the status comparing the current date to the event date in my MYSQL. All of my dates are coming out as "Passed" although one of the event dates are in the future. I have tried multiple different methods and I can't seem to figure out why this continues to happen.

```
$sql = "SELECT Event_id, title, event_date, location, description, status FROM events";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // Show each data returned by mysql
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // date_default_timezone_get('America/indiana');

// foreach ($row as $row['events']) {
     //
     // $time = strtotime('10/16/2003');
     //
     // $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
$current_datetime = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
$sqldate = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($row['event_date']));


       if (strtotime($current_datetime) > strtotime($sqldate)) {
           mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET status = 'Passed'");
       }
       elseif (strtotime($current_datetime) === strtotime($sqldate)) {
           mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET status = 'Ongoing'");
       }
       else {
           mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET status = 'Upcoming'");
       //}


}
?>

<div class="event">
    <p> Title : <?php echo $row["title"]; ?> </p>
    <p> Date: <?php echo $row["event_date"]?> </p>
    <p> Location: <?php echo $row["location"]?> </p>
    <p> Description: <?php echo $row["description"]?> </p>
    <p> Status: <?php echo $row["status"]?> </p>
</div>
</body>
<?php

}
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

// Closing mysql connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

// also check your date that getting from SQL query and change the current date time format

```
<?php 

    $current_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    print_r(strtotime($current_datetime));

    $sqldate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(date('2019-12-06 12:27:54'))); // I have hardcoded the date time here

    print_r(strtotime($sqldate));

    if (strtotime($current_datetime) > strtotime($sqldate)) {
       // mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET status = 'Passed'");
       echo "passed";
    }
    elseif (strtotime($current_datetime) == strtotime($sqldate)) {
       // mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET status = 'Ongoing'");
       echo "Ongoing";  
    }
    else {
       // mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET status = 'Upcoming'");
       echo "Upcoming";
    }
```

Comment: This did not worked, I literally do not what else to try. I think I have exhausted my option

Comment: Each status is coming out as "passed". I'm not sure if it is setting each status based on the first one or if there is an error reading the current date.

Comment: @TwanyeaDonaldson then first check your current time by printing the variable, if current time is not matched with the printed output, then the fault is with your php.ini default timings. Kindly change your `ini` configurations timing with your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use a loop here your can run these query separately like this.

```
$current_datetime = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET status = 'Passed' WHERE event_date < $current_datetime");
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET status = 'Ongoing' WHERE event_date == $current_datetime");
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET status = 'Upcoming' WHERE event_date > $current_datetime");
```

And please check syntax I am not using PHP from a long time I am just sharing basic idea to you.

Comment: None of this works, I'm not sure how else to make it work.